# My vba macro for aligning a shape or graphic to the top right corner of the page in word isn't working

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros, shapes

```
Sub alignGraphicElementToTopRightCornerOfPage()
'
' alignGraphicElementToTopRightCornerOfPage Macro
'
'
    Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignTops, True
    Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignRights, True
End Sub
```

See the difference between what happens when I use the macro, and what happens when I manually do the multiple commands from the ribbon. I created the macro using the record feature.

The macro makes the item go off the page which is undesired behaviour, which is not what happened when I recorded the macro.

[image: microsoft word vba macro align graphic or shape to the top righ corner of the page]

Why isn't it working? I recorded the macro correctly. Is there any vba code I need to change or add to it?

Comment: If anything it looks like the VBA is aligning the center of the object to the top of the page while correctly aligning the right hand side. Oddness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem with an addition of new lines for the VBA macro.

```
Sub alignGraphicElementToTopRightCornerOfPage()
'
' alignGraphicElementToTopRightCornerOfPage Macro
'
'
    Selection.ShapeRange.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapFront
    ' choose the wrapping type
    ' the following values are good "3" "wdWrapFront" an "wdWrapTight"
    ' I don't know what "3" does but Microsoft Office 2007 uses it
    
    Selection.ShapeRange.RelativeHorizontalPosition = _
        wdRelativeHorizontalPositionColumn
    Selection.ShapeRange.RelativeVerticalPosition = _
        wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
    Selection.ShapeRange.RelativeHorizontalSize = wdRelativeHorizontalSizePage
    Selection.ShapeRange.RelativeVerticalSize = wdRelativeVerticalSizePage
    ' these commands are needed if the wrapping type is "3" or "wdWrapFront"
    ' ensure the shape is aligned to the top right corner of the page
        ' This also fixes the formatting problems when the page has text on it,
        ' to prevent an extra line break or blank space appearing on the screen
        ' that the user did not intentionally create
    
    Selection.ShapeRange.WrapFormat.DistanceTop = CentimetersToPoints(0)
    Selection.ShapeRange.WrapFormat.DistanceBottom = CentimetersToPoints(0)
    ' these commands are needed if the wrapping type is "wdWrapTight"

    Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignTops, True
    Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignRights, True
    ' start aligning the image to the top right of the page
    
End Sub
```